# rospy.Subscriber

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it necessarily to have a `def callback` in the rospy.Subscriber? I am asking because I came across one question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/219029/getting-depth-information-from-point-using-python). In that question, the asker uses a Subscribe method without `def callback`.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319982/rospy.subscriber/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2019-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not necessary to have a `def callback` in the rospy.Subscriber constructor(It's an optional argument). However, if no callback functions are set, the messages won't be processed. You can later add callbacks using the `add_callback()` ([source](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html))

If you look at the question that you are referring to, he is using `message_filter` to approximately synchronise messages and process them together in a single callback, which he registers by calling `self.ts.registerCallback(self.callback)`.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2019-04-01**:
thank you for the answer